# Fetch an association whether it exists or not

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I perform a simple query like this, but loose all the objects that do not have an association with episodes:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT p,e
        FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Place p
        JOIN p.episodes e
        WHERE p.id = :id'
        )
            ->setParameter('id',$id);
```

**This is a simple asso:**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Episode", mappedBy="place")
 */
protected $episodes;
```

My query automatically discards the objects that have an empty $episodes Collection. Does anyone know why? I am sure it makes sense but I can't figure this out.
Is there a way to fetch the object anyway whether there is or there is not the asso episodes?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of just a `JOIN`.

JOIN gives only records from the left that also have a record on the right. 
LEFT JOIN gives records from the left regardless of if they also have a record on the right.

Comment: You're a legend @simshaun! Quickest response ever! Works perfectly now! I can only accept the answer in 5 mn..